# What is the difference between "sina qua non" "part and parcel" and "sum and substance"?

Tags: meaning, usage, vocabulary

TAKE THE FREE DICTIONARY, for example:

DEFINITIONS:

1. SINE QUA NON:  something that is essential before you can achieve something else
2. PART AND PARCEL: to be a feature of something, especially a feature that cannot be avoided:
3. SUM AND SUBSTANCE:  The central or most important idea, aspect, or part of something; the essence or summary of something.

EXAMPLES:

1. SINE QUA NON:

Some consider a good education to be the sine qua non of a successful career.

An interest in children is a sine qua non of teaching

2. PART AND PARCEL:

Dealing with tantrums is part and parcel of raising a toddler.

I'm afraid customer complaints are part and parcel of this job

3. SUM AND SUBSTANCE:

The sum and substance of their platform is financial conservatism.

The sum and substance of her argument is that a redistribution of wealth would spur the economy into huge gains.

In each of these examples, these three terms seem to refer to "something that acts as the main central component or essential part of a larger system"

Comment: They are vastly different in register. One way to get a feeling for words is to use NGram and read through the results.

Comment: Notice that 'sine qua non' and 'sum and substance' are closely synonymous (the essentials) whereas '_to be 'part and parcel' of something_ is _to be a feature of something, **especially AN** essential part_.  *'Dealing with tantrums is the essential part of raising a toddler.'

Comment: A *sine qua non* (Latin for 'without which, not) is something you have to have before you can even start doing the activity in question. This is not the same as 'something you are bound to come across while doing it'.